# Error creating Envers's EntityManagerFactory when annotations are present

Tags: hibernate-envers

Envers looks easy. Just add some hibernate properties in your `persistence.xml` (eventlisteners), and annotate the entities you want to audit.

I am testing this on an application using Hibernate. Here is some pom info:

- org.hibernate.hibernate-entitymanager:3.4.0.GA
- org.hibernate.hibernate-annotations:3.4.0.GA
- org.hibernate.hibernate:3.2.6.GA
- org.jboss.envers.jboss-envers:1.2.1.GA-hibernate-3.3

If I insert *no* annotations, my app context is loaded fine. But if I insert one, I am unable to build EntityManagerFactory.

```
(...)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.metadata.AuditMetadataGenerator.generateInheritanceMappingData(AuditMetadataGenerator.java:305)
    at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.metadata.AuditMetadataGenerator.generateFirstPass(AuditMetadataGenerator.java:353)
    at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.EntitiesConfigurator.configure(EntitiesConfigurator.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.AuditConfiguration.(AuditConfiguration.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.AuditConfiguration.getFor(AuditConfiguration.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener.initialize(AuditEventListener.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.event.EventListeners$1.processListener(EventListeners.java:198)
    at org.hibernate.event.EventListeners.processListeners(EventListeners.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.event.EventListeners.initializeListeners(EventListeners.java:194)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

org.jboss.envers.jboss-envers:1.2.1.GA-hibernate-3.3 works with hibernate-3.3
did you try to use newer version?